# Functions not firing in correct order even though first function calls second

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My aim was to use a boolean stored in state to update a dropdown menu to either show or remain hidden. I wrote two functions, 'toggleHander' (triggered by a click event) which toggles the boolean state and then calls the next function - 'dropdownClickHandler'. 'dropdownClickHandler' adds a 'show' css class (or not) dependent on the state of the boolean held in state hence updating the drop down menu.

My problem (I think) is that the second function ('dropdownClickHandler') is called before the first ('toggleHandler') - even though the 'toggleHandler' is directly triggered by a click event and should only call the second function after setState has completed. This results in a user needing to click twice before the drop down shows (instead of once).

I'm not sure if this is something to do with hoisting or the asynchronous nature of setState? Or perhaps something else?

Any help appreciated

FYI - I've tried changing the initial boolean state to true and the menu works. I just don't understand the order of function calls

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/k-i-r-o-n/pen/vwERzP

Suspected offending code:

```
toggleHandler = () => {
  this.setState(
    {addClass: !this.state.addClass},
    () => console.log('in toggle', this.state),                             
      this.dropdownClickHandler()
  ); 
}


dropdownClickHandler = () => {
  console.log('in drop', this.state);
  this.state.addClass === true ? boxClass = ["dropdownContent", "dropdownContent__show"] : boxClass = ["dropdownContent"]
}
```

Comment: Hi. Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside the `dropdownClickHandler` and tracing its callstack through the development tools to see who fired it?

Comment: 1. The syntax is `this.setState(newState, callback);` but you have a third parameter 2. changing `boxClass` doesn't update the state and thus doesn't cause a re-render, which is why the change only becomes visible in the next re-render: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eaNMNp

Comment: Try moving `boxClass` into state (and then use setState inside `dropdownClickHandler` to change it), in your `render` use `this.state.boxClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proper syntax:

```
toggleHandler = () => {
  this.setState(
    {addClass: !this.state.addClass},
    () => {
      console.log('in toggle', this.state),                             
      this.dropdownClickHandler()
    }
  ); 
}
```

but (as stated in comments) `dropdownClickHandler()` won't work correctly ...

...you don't need it at all (basic conditional renderings):

```
render() {
  const boxClass = this.state.addClass ? "dropdownContent dropdownContent__show" : "dropdownContent"

  return (
    <div className={boxClass} >
```

or even simpler

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className={"dropdownContent "+ this.state.addClass && "dropdownContent__show"} >
```

Comment: Thanks everyone - I've updated the code using the knowledge shared